# Create a list based on list of tuples (value, indices)

Tags: python, list

I have in input a list of tuples with a string and a list of integers. The integers goes from `1` to `n` and they appear at most one time:

```
l = [('red', [0,2,5]),
     ('yellow', [1,4]),
     ('red', [6])]
```

I want to create a list of `n` strings where if the index appear in one of the lists, it's value will be the corresponding string and if it doesn't appear a default value will be applied, for example `white`.

This is the expected output:

```
result = ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'red']
```

This is my code, it works fine but I'm wondering **if there is a faster way to do it**:

```
result = ['white'] * n

for t in l:
    for i in t[1]:
        result[i] = t[0]
```

Edit:

I forgot to say that `n` is about 300.

Comment: It cannot be done faster that your `O(n)` code.

Comment: you have to touch every value in the dictionary and then every element in the list. So time complexity will remain the same. The code however can be short.

Comment: I know, but i'm wondering if there is some function to fo it that maybe is faster of nested for loops.

Comment: @Vishal (and quamrana) while time complexity does stay the same, in general python has multiple ways to do iteration-based things and often the execution time is greatly different (e.g., looping vs list comprehensions vs numpy-based approaches)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all "is there a faster way to do this" questions in python (and, I believe, in most languages as well), the answer is **measure it, then you'll know**.

I took the code in the answers proposed so far and timed it:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

n = 7
l = [('red', [0,2,5]),
     ('yellow', [1,4]),
     ('red', [6])]

def OP_approach():
    result = ['white'] * n
    for t in l:
        for i in t[1]:
            result[i] = t[0]
    return result

def yatu_approach():
    d = {j:i[0] for i in l for j in i[1]}
    return [d.get(i, 'white') for i in range(len(d)+1)]

def blue_note_approach():
    x = np.empty(7, dtype='<U5')
    x.fill('white')
    for a, b in l:
        x[b] = a
    return x

timeit.timeit(OP_approach, number=10000)
timeit.timeit(yatu_approach, number=10000)
timeit.timeit(blue_note_approach, number=10000)
```

To my surprise, this is the result on my machine (arm64 board):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(OP_approach, number=10000)
0.033418309001717716
>>> timeit.timeit(yatu_approach, number=10000)
0.10994336503790691
>>> timeit.timeit(blue_note_approach, number=10000)
0.3608954470255412
```

It seems, then, that for the sample data given the simple double-loop is faster than both other options. Do keep in mind however that, as pointed out by @yatu, these algorithms scale very differently and the choice of which to use depends on the expected size of the problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you, I will do tests on my machine too because in my code I have greater instances of this problem, maybe something can change.

Comment: Try with 100.000. OPs solution does not scale well

Comment: @yatu the point of the answer is not to provide the "fastest" solution, but rather to suggest trying the alternatives and see what works best *in the specific setup the OP has*. Of course, at different scales different problems emerge, but scaling to huge dimensions was never mentioned in the question, nor presented as a requirement.

Comment: OP has not specified an `n`, so it is safe to assume IMO that the better the solution scales for high `n`s the better the solution works? How do you define how well a solution works if it is not in ter @GPhilo

Comment: OP posted a sample, which I used to evaluate three algorithms. If the OP cares for the case where N is 100k, it's trivial enough to generate a suitable list and rerun the script. My point is still the same, though: measuring is the way to go when comparing algorithms for performance.

Comment: In terms of performance* did not end sentence @GPhilo Yes sure, measuring is the way. And an accurate measure includes a good idea of how well a solution scales. It is clearly incomplete to say solution `a` is faster than `b` for an `n` = 1000. You need to know how well it scales, and know when one will be more convenient than the other depending on `n`

Comment: I'm checking with the timings and bluenote's solution is 100 times faster than OP's  for n=100.000

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is, yes. Python's for loops are known to be slow, which is why I was surprised by my results. Together with the scale of the problem, though, there are other factors that can affect the speed (like the platform used). I'm not saying "always use the for loop, it's the fastest option", I'm just saying that for the given sample, these three algorithms perform like this. The OP can choose the one to use given his use-case scenario, since he has full information about the type of problem he has to solve.

Comment: Yes I agree with everything except for `for the given sample`. You assumed a particular `n`, yet we have no idea of how large is the file or the amount of data OP is dealing with, that is why having a complete understanding of the time complexity (i.e. n_samples vs time) is so important. One solution may be better for n=1000, and another for n=10000 @GPhilo . So I consider your answer incomplete and misleading. (Though I do agree that other answers SHOULD have included timings)

Comment: In my program `n` is just about 300. I made some tesst and unfotunately my solution with for loops it's the fastest.

Comment: I did another test that showed different results. If most of the indices remain with the default value, the for loops is little bit faster, but if the new values covers most of the list, the dictionary approach is way faster, about 3 or 3,5 times faster.

Comment: @dome yes, this is possible. As I said, there is no "this is the absolute best, use it always" algorithm. It's up to you to choose the one you believe it's sufficiently efficient, based on the test results. Also: there are probably other ways out there to solve this problem, I only collected and timed the ones proposed in the answers, it doesn't mean the best one is necessarily here among them

Comment: Yes, of course; I was just wondering if there was other way to solve this problem that I didnt thought. I'm a programmer but I started python just some months ago and I'm still learning how to optimize code in this language (that some times behaves in strange manners).

Answer (score 2):

Only by using numpy

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.empty(7, dtype='<U6')
x.fill('white')

for a, b in l:
    x[b] = a
```

where `U6` means a unicode string of length 6 (at most)

Comment: `<U6` because yellow `</nitpick>`

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [('red', [0,2,5]),
     ('yellow', [1,4]),
     ('red', [6])]
# get len of result
n = max(l, key = itemgetter(1))[1] 

# initialize the result list
result = ['white'] * 7

for t in l:
    for i in t[1]:
        result[i] = t[0]
```

Output :

```
result = ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'red', 'red']
```